# Template rendered fired before all the dom is generated

Tags: meteor

I have this code that worked on previous versions of Meteor:

```html
<template name='posts'>
  {{# each posts }}
    <div class='post'>some text</div>
  {{/ each }}
</template>
```

```js
Template.posts.rendered = function() {
  this.findAll('post').doSomething();
}

Template.posts.helpers({
  posts: function() {
    Meteos.subscribe('posts', this._id);
    return Posts.find({ someId: this._id });
  }
});
```

Now I'm using Meteor 0.9.4 and the code in the rendered is called before the dom inside the each is generate, so `this.findAll('post').doSomething()` do nothing. How can I solve this?

Comment: David, you're right. I doesn't found that when searched for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem you're coming across is that not all of your data has been loaded on the client when the rendered callback fires.

Probably the easiest way to work around this is to put each post in a template and use that template's rendered callback instead:

```
<template name='posts'>
  {{# each posts }}
    {{> post}}
  {{/ each }}
</template>

<template name='post'>
  <div class='post'>some text</div>
</template>

Template.post.rendered = function() {
  this.find('.post').doSomething();
}
```

With this code you will be 100% sure that the post has been displayed, and as a bonus it will work if new posts are added and removed while someone is on the page.